# Configuring WSO2 IS as a key manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am new to WSO2 IS and WSO2 APIM. I have an all in one instance VM configured with IS(version 5.11.0) and APIM (version 3.2.0). I am trying to use WSO2 IS as the key manager following the below documentation.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/

After configuring the databases (WSO2SHARED_DB & WSO2AM_DB), IS and APIM as mentioned in the documentation above, I published a GraphQL API and subscribed with the Default Application. But I am getting the following errors while trying to generate the production or sandbox keys.

Error on APIM side

```
AbstractKeyManager Cannot create OAuth application  : admin_DefaultApplication_SANDBOX
    org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.kmclient.KeyManagerClientException: Received status code: 500 Reason:
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.kmclient.KMClientErrorDecoder.decode_aroundBody0(KMClientErrorDecoder.java:32) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.kmclient.KMClientErrorDecoder.decode(KMClientErrorDecoder.java:27) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:96) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
            at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
            at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
            at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy480.createApplication(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication_aroundBody0(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:138) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:100) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication_aroundBody8(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:150) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:124) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication_aroundBody6(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:120) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:117) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete_aroundBody2(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:78) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:66) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute_aroundBody0(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:54) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:47) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration_aroundBody144(APIConsumerImpl.java:4202) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:4055) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.applicationsApplicationIdGenerateKeysPost(ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.java:541) [classes/:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.ApplicationsApi.applicationsApplicationIdGenerateKeysPost(ApplicationsApi.java:126) [classes/:?]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.4.0.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.4.0.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:101) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.4.0.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.0.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_275]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_275]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_275]
    [2021-01-18 05:11:13,408] ERROR - APIUtil Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.
    org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Cannot create OAuth application  : admin_DefaultApplication_SANDBOX
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractKeyManager.handleException_aroundBody12(AbstractKeyManager.java:265) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractKeyManager.handleException(AbstractKeyManager.java:263) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication_aroundBody0(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:147) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:100) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication_aroundBody8(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:150) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:124) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication_aroundBody6(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:120) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:117) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete_aroundBody2(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:78) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:66) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute_aroundBody0(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:54) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:47) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration_aroundBody144(APIConsumerImpl.java:4202) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:4055) [org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.applicationsApplicationIdGenerateKeysPost(ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.java:541) [classes/:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.ApplicationsApi.applicationsApplicationIdGenerateKeysPost(ApplicationsApi.java:126) [classes/:?]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
            at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat_9.0.31.wso2v1.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.4.0.jar:?]
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110) [org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.4.0.jar:?]
```

EDIT:
error on IS side

```
ERROR {org.wso2.is.key.manager.operations.endpoint.impl.DcrApiServiceImpl} - Internal Server Error org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.dcr.exception.DCRMServerException: Error occurred while creating application with application name:  admin_DefaultApplication_SANDBOX
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException.error(IdentityException.java:100)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.dcr.util.DCRMUtils.generateServerException(DCRMUtils.java:123)
            at org.wso2.is.key.manager.operations.endpoint.dcr.service.DCRMService.createOAuthApp(DCRMService.java:470)
            at org.wso2.is.key.manager.operations.endpoint.dcr.service.DCRMService.createOAuthApplication(DCRMService.java:344)
            at org.wso2.is.key.manager.operations.endpoint.dcr.service.DCRMService.registerApplication(DCRMService.java:85)
            at org.wso2.is.key.manager.operations.endpoint.impl.DcrApiServiceImpl.registerApplication(DcrApiServiceImpl.java:111)
            at org.wso2.is.key.manager.operations.endpoint.DcrApi.registerApplication(DcrApi.java:104)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
            at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201)
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104)
            at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
            at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
            at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:296)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:215)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:271)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:107)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.valve.CORSValve.invoke(CORSValve.java:98)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:102)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:123)
            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.IdentityOAuthClientException: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code' grant type is not allowed.
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl.handleClientError(OAuthAdminServiceImpl.java:353)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl.validateGrantTypes(OAuthAdminServiceImpl.java:346)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl.registerAndRetrieveOAuthApplicationData(OAuthAdminServiceImpl.java:267)
            at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminService.registerAndRetrieveOAuthApplicationData(OAuthAdminService.java:133)
            at org.wso2.is.key.manager.operations.endpoint.dcr.service.DCRMService.createOAuthApp(DCRMService.java:468)
```

Can someone point me on what is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the doc you are referring it says IS 5.10.0 not 5.11.0. Could you please check with IS 5.10.0 as well. Further as per stack trace

```
'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code' grant type is not allowed.
```

Looks like 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code' is not defined under supported grant types. Can you please verify below entry in <WSO2IS_HOME>/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml ?

```
<SupportedGrantType>
    <GrantTypeName>urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code</GrantTypeName>
        <GrantTypeHandlerImplClass>org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.device.grant.DeviceFlowGrant</GrantTypeHandlerImplClass>
        <GrantTypeValidatorImplClass>org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.device.grant.DeviceFlowGrantValidator</GrantTypeValidatorImplClass>
        <IdTokenAllowed>true</IdTokenAllowed>
</SupportedGrantType>
```